# TypeError: possibleTypes[supertype].forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

This my code.

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import RouteCollector from "./routeCollector";

import "./index.css";
import possibleTypes from "./tools/graphqlCodeGenerator/possibleTypes.json";

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  possibleTypes,
});

const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql",
  credentials: "include",
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
});

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <RouteCollector />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I am using the packages  `" @ apollo / client ":" ^ 3.0.2 "`, `"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",`   `"graphql": "^15.3.0"`,`"react": "^16.13.1",`

when I run the program I get the error

> TypeError: possibleTypes[supertype].forEach is not a function

How to fix the error ?

Comment: Which line of your code throws this error?

Comment: @RezaBehzadpour  `const cache = new InMemoryCache({possibleTypes,})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GraphQL Code Generator, you should make sure you're using the `possibleTypes` property of the object generated by the `fragment-matcher` plugin, like this:

```
import introspectionResult from '../introspection-result';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  possibleTypes: introspectionResult.possibleTypes,
});
```

You can't pass the entire object that's generated.

You also need to make sure you're setting `apolloClientVersion` to `3` in your codegen config to ensure you're generating the correct object.